# Collapse Pandas rows to elliminate NaN entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's consider the following DataFrame

| Name | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tom | 10.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| tom | NaN | 15.0 | NaN | NaN |
| tom | NaN | NaN | 20.0 | NaN |
| tom | NaN | NaN | NaN | 25.0 |
| tom | 30.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| tom | NaN | NaN | NaN | 40.0 |
| john | 1.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| john | NaN | 2.0 | NaN | NaN |
| john | NaN | NaN | 3.0 | NaN |
| john | NaN | NaN | NaN | 4.0 |
| john | 5.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| john | NaN | 6.0 | NaN | NaN |
| john | NaN | NaN | 7.0 | NaN |
| john | NaN | NaN | NaN | 8.0 |

I want to collapse it to limit the amount of `NaN` values in the DataFrame - can be sequential, i.e. combine the neighboring rows if possible, but all I care about is that the values of columns `A-D` correspond to the same `Name` after the collapse

My perfect outcome would be

| Name | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tom | 10.0 | 15.0 | 20.0 | 25.0 |
| tom | 30.0 | NaN | NaN | 40.0 |
| john | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4.0 |
| john | 5.0 | 6.0 | 7.0 | 8.0 |

From what I understand, Pandas `groupby('Name')` will not do the trick, because it will leave one entry for each name.

If that is of any help, I use a dictionary to create the dataframe. The dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    "a": {
        "tom": [10.0, 30.0],
        "john": [1.0, 5.0]
    },
    "b": {
        "tom": [15.0],
        "john": [2.0, 6.0]
    },
    .....
}
```

So, basically, I am taking every number in the dictionary then create a row with just this number, and then combine all of the rows.

Is there a simple way to collapse the resulting DataFrame or build a more compact DataFrame given such a dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `.groupby` + `.transform` (where you "move" the values up). Then drop rows which contain all `NaN` values:

```py
print(
    df.set_index("Name")
    .groupby(level=0)
    .transform(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda k: pd.isna(k)))
    .dropna(axis=0, how="all")
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
   Name     A     B     C     D
0   tom  10.0  15.0  20.0  25.0
1   tom  30.0   NaN   NaN  40.0
2  john   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
3  john   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot.